# How to get $[z^n]\displaystyle\frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k} = {n-1 \choose k-1}?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

> How does one get the following result $[z^n]\displaystyle\frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k} = {n-1 \choose k-1}?$

Where is the error in my computation?

$$\begin{align} [z^n]z^k\cdot (1-z)^{-k} &= [z^{n-k}](1-z)^{-k} \\ &=[z^{n-k}]\displaystyle\sum_{k \geq 0}{n + k - 1 \choose k }(-z)^k(1)^{-n-k}(-1)^k \\ &=  [z^{n-k}]\sum_{k \geq 0}{n + k - 1 \choose k }z^k(-1)^{2k}  \\
&= [z^{n-k}]\sum_{k \geq 0}{n + k - 1 \choose k }z^k\end{align}.$$

From here, I want the coefficient of $z^{n-k}$ in the sum, so I want that $k=n-k$ which happens when $n=2k$. But then something seems off here, i'm not even able to get the term with $z^{n-k}$ in the summation.

Comment: It may in part depend on what $[x]$ means.

Comment: You have used $k$ as a specific number in the problem and also as an index variable in your solution.  This is going to lead to serious confusion.

Comment: @David I thought about this, however, if I was unsure whether changing $k$ in $(1-z)^{-k}$ to say $j$ would change the meaning of the problem since I had powers of $k$ at the start of the problem. I will try it with $j$.

Comment: If you're not happy changing that $k$, then change the other $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the index of summation
to something other than
$n$ or $k$.
Then you get,
replacing $k$ by $s$
as in the Wikipedia article,

$\begin{align} 
[z^n]z^s\cdot (1-z)^{-s} 
&= [z^{n-s}](1-z)^{-s} \\ 
&=[z^{n-s}]\displaystyle\sum_{k \geq 0}{s+k - 1 \choose k }(z)^s\\ 
&={s+n-s - 1 \choose n-s }\\ 
&={n - 1 \choose n-s }\\ 
&={n - 1 \choose (n-1)-(n-s) }\\ 
&={n - 1 \choose s-1 }\\ 
\end{align}
$